# Child component fetches data, which should be passed to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

In my react component I do get some data from graphQL server using react-apollo.
That's working fine, but this component is a **child** component and I need to get the graphQL data to a parent component. Is this possible at all or do I have to change my structure?

**Child**

```
export class Child extends Component {
  const { contentList } = this.props
  render () {
    contentList.map(elm => return <div>elm</div>)
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(
    gql`
      query {
        contentList {
          _id
          title
        }
      }
    `, { name: 'contentList' }
  )
)(Child)
```

**Parent**

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data = null // <-- Need to get the data of child here
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state
    // Now I can use the data, which is fetched by the child component
    return <Child />
  }
}
```

Comment: You can pass a function of the parent the parent to the child as prop, then call it from the child, passing the data. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breact%5D+pass+data+to+parent

Comment: @ChrisG But how should the call from the child should look like? The data is attached to the child component by compose... I know how to do that if I'm using a function, like clicking on a button an child component. But in this case the graphql data is confusing me...

Comment: Looking at the Parent's `render()` function, it looks like you want to access the child's data before it is created...? I don't think that'll work.

Comment: @ChrisG I was thinking of rendering parent, then rendering child, which gets the data, then pass the data back to the parent state, now rerender parent component with the passed data...

Comment: Don't change the state inside `render()`, because that will result in an infinite loop. Just move the fetching of the data to the Parent and this entire question will disappear into thin air.

Comment: @ChrisG I exactly tried this and I got the infinite loop. I don't know how to do it the right way.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Fetch the data in the Parent? If so, show the code you've used.

Comment: @ChrisG No, I fetched the data in the child - as I showed in in the post.

Comment: Ok, so did you miss my comment where I told you `Just move the fetching of the data to the Parent and this entire question will disappear into thin air.`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function of parent to the childComponent via props and invoke that function from child when you have data.

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data = null // <-- Need to get the data of child here
    }
  }
handleData(data){
//you can use data here
}

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state
    // Now I can use the data, which is fetched by the child component
    return <Child parentHandler="this.handleData" />
  }
}


export class Child extends Component {
  const { contentList, parentHandler } = this.props;
//call parentHandler with the data when you have data
  render () {
    contentList.map(elm => return <div>elm</div>)
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(
    gql`
      query {
        contentList {
          _id
          title
        }
      }
    `, { name: 'contentList' }
  )
)(Child)
```